# Loading a modal form with data in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Trying to learn Angular ... and

I'm missing something really obvious here, I'm sure of it. However, all of the examples, fiddles or plunkers I'm finding deal with validating create forms, not update forms.

My application is creating a modal form to add/edit client data.  If a valid clientId is passed in, the form is opened as an edit and the data is loaded into the form.

When I load the values, I'm only assigning the value to the modal's property. Since its only a value, it doesn't have an $invalid function or any of the other nice form methods.  Without that, the validation doesn't work.  What's the proper way to load data into a form in Angular so that it can be validated?  Thanks!

```
angular.module('app').controller("clientController",
    function ($scope, $modalInstance, dataService, clientId) {
        $scope.clientForm = {}
        $scope.clientForm.clientId = clientId;

        $modalInstance.opened.then(function () {
            if (clientId > 0) {
                dataService.getClient(clientId).then(function (clientData) {
                    $scope.clientForm.name = clientData.Name;
                    $scope.clientForm.address1 = clientData.Address1;
                    $scope.clientForm.address2 = clientData.Address2;
                    $scope.clientForm.city = clientData.City;
                    $scope.clientForm.stateId = clientData.StateId;
                    $scope.clientForm.zip = clientData.Zip;
                    $scope.clientForm.email = clientData.Email;
                });
            };
        });

        $scope.ok = function () {
            $scope.clientForm.$submitted = true;
            if ($scope.clientForm.$valid) {
                $modalInstance.close($scope.clientForm);
            }
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    }
)
```

And for the form:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="ClientEdit.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title"><span>Client</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body col-md-12">
        <form name="clientForm" novalidate>                        
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label text-right" for="txtclientName">Name: </label>
                <div class="col-md-6"><input class="form-control input-sm" id="txtclientName" type="text" ng-model="clientForm.name" required /></div>
                <p ng-show="clientForm.name.$invalid">Name is required.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label text-right" for="txtAddressLine1">Address 1: </label>
                <div class="col-md-6"><input class="form-control input-sm" id="txtAddressLine1" type="text" ng-model="clientForm.address1" /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label text-right" for="txtAddressLine2">Address 2: </label>
                <div class="col-md-6"><input class="form-control input-sm" id="txtAddressLine2" type="text" ng-model="clientForm.address2" /></div>.
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label text-right" for="txtCity">City: </label>
                <div class="col-md-2"><input class="form-control input-sm" id="txtCity" type="text" ng-model="clientForm.city" /></div>
                <label class="col-md-1 control-label text-right" for="txtZip">Zip: </label>
                <div class="col-md-2"><input class="form-control input-sm" id="txtZip" type="text" ng-model="clientForm.zip" /></div>
            </div>                        
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label text-right" for="txtEmail">Email: </label>
                <div class="col-md-6"><input class="form-control input-sm" id="txtEmail" type="email" ng-model="clientForm.email" /></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()" ng-disabled="clientForm.$invalid">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: name attribute is missing in your input field

Comment: angular validation works with field which has name attribute and you are missing that attribute.

Comment: I added the name attribute and I changed the ng-model to bind to properties on the scope, not the form. Both steps were required. Thanks